# Custom sound not played when push notification arrives

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I am having some trouble setting the message sound for my app.

I am Newly work on Push Notification. Notification is working fine .but I'm unable to add Custom sound when push notification arrives. Receive payload data to server. In which push notification delegate method to add custom ring code.

```
Code

  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application       didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *setting = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:setting];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];


    NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    if (notification) {
        NSString *cancelTitle = @"Reject";
        NSString *showTitle = @"Accept";
        NSString *message = @"This is Testing";
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]      initWithTitle:@"Order"
                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                                  otherButtonTitles:showTitle, nil];
        [alertView show];
    } else {
        // from the springboard
    }

    return YES;
}
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
        UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
       if (state == UIApplicationStateActive ) {

           NSString *ring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"sound"]];

           NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],ring]];

           NSError *error;

           audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
           audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
           [audioPlayer play];


            NSString *cancelTitle = @"Close";
            NSString *showTitle = @"Show";
            NSString *message = @"This is Testing";
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some title"
                                                                message:message
                                                               delegate:self
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                                      otherButtonTitles:showTitle, nil];
            [alertView show];
          }else{



          }
```

Comment: which type of sound file you have used? , i mean .caf , .wav etc

Comment: once check file is exist or not, which is coming from notification data and no need to give NSBundle main bundle resource path if it exist in main bundle , u can directly give filename

Comment: you can give like this, [NSURL fileURLWithPath: ring]

Comment: ring must be contain file extension also

Comment: .wav file to use play custom ring

Comment: Actually the sound is played automatically if a file with the value of the `sound` key in the payload exists in the application bundle (including file extension). There is no extra code needed. APNS supports `aiff`, `wav`, or `caf` formats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code, it will be help you out

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    {
            UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
           if (state == UIApplicationStateActive ) {

          //     NSString *ring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"sound"]];

         //      NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],ring]];

           //    NSError *error;

          //     audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
         //      audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
         //      [audioPlayer play];

         NSString *path =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"circuit___ios_7" ofType:@"mp3"];
              SystemSoundID soundID;
                AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path], &soundID);

         AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);

                NSString *cancelTitle = @"Close";
                NSString *showTitle = @"Show";
                NSString *message = @"This is Testing";
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some title"
                                                                    message:message
                                                                   delegate:self
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                                          otherButtonTitles:showTitle, nil];
                [alertView show];
              }else{



              }
}
```